# How to add underline to unselected tabs in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How to add underline to unselected tabs, like this: [image]

you can see it is gray colour for unselected tabs, and blue for selected. I want the Undelined color of Unselected Tabs according to my app color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tabs to achieve this

```flutter
Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text:"About"), // you can specify pages here if you want
                Tab(text:"Reg"),
                Tab(text:"Services"),
               
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Text("1"),
              Text("2"),
              Text("3"),
         
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: basically i want to change the colour from silver to other one like red. is it possible or not?

Comment: indicatorColor : your desired color

Comment: if i use indicatorColor : Colors.red, then it Changes the Selected Tab color, i want to change the color of Others.